# Change direction of arrows in geom_spoke

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way in `geom_spoke()` to get arrows to point to the direction of the given data? If I have data with a location (x,y) and an angle, it seems ideal to me to use `geom_spoke`, but I would expect to be able to choose in which direction the arrows should point (away from the coordinates or pointing to them; I want the latter).

In this example, I added `geom_point()` to illustrate the location of my data; the radius is chosen randomly, so I want the arrow heads where the points are now (and instead of the points, of course):

```
set.seed(1)
df       <- expand.grid(x = 1:10, y=1:10)
df$angle <- runif(100, 0, 2*pi)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point()        +
  coord_equal()       +
  geom_spoke(aes(angle = angle), radius = 0.7, arrow=arrow(length = unit(0.2,"cm")))
```

[image]

Comment: FYI: I posted [an issue](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1734) regarding (lack of) documentation of the `arrow` argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `arrow` in `geom_spoke` refers to `grid::arrow`, which has the `ends` argument:

> One of `"last"`, `"first"`, or `"both"`, indicating which ends of the line to draw arrow heads.

Because you didn't explicitly set the `ends` argument, the default value of `"last"` was used, i.e. arrow at the end of the segment.

A small example:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, angle = angle)) +
  geom_point()
```

Default value of `ends`:

```
# omitting the ends argument, like in your attempt:
p + geom_spoke(arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm")), radius = 0.7)

# or writing out the ends argument explicitly:
p + geom_spoke(arrow = arrow(ends = "last", length = unit(0.2, "cm")), radius = 0.7)
```

Arrow at the start of the segment, set `ends = "first"`:

```
p + geom_spoke(arrow = arrow(ends = "first"), radius = 0.7)
```

[image]