# geom_segment arrow direction

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot some up and down arrows using `geom_segment`. I splitted my dataset in 2 for the data that need an up-facing arrow and the down-facing ones.

But on both plots the arrow is facing upwards. how can this be reversed? Is there a variable that i'm missing?

The dataset I'm using looks like the following:

```
GENE   START    END        STRAND
A      3000000  3000312    +
B      3001233  3090123    -
```

The positive strands need an `up-facing` arrow, while the negative ones, need a `down-facing`.

here's my code:

```
# split the dataset in '+' and '-'
up.arrows <- genes.data[which(genes.data$STRAND=='+'),]
up.arrows.x <- runif(length(up.arrows$START), min = 0, max = length(up.arrows))

down.arrows <- genes.data[which(genes.data$STRAND=='-'),]
down.arrows.x <- runif(length(down.arrows$START), min = 0, max = length(down.arrows))
```

I'm using runif, because I don't care about the `x-axis` position. My main concern is the `y-axis`.

```
ggplot(up.arrows, aes(up.arrows.x, up.arrows$START)) +
    geom_segment(aes(xend=up.arrows.x, yend=up.arrows$STOP), 
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, "cm")),
                 colour = 'green4') + 
    geom_text_repel(size = 3,
                    aes(label = up.arrows$GENE),
                    color = 'black') +
    theme_classic(base_size = 16)

ggplot(down.arrows, aes(down.arrows.x, down.arrows$START)) +
    geom_segment(aes(xend=down.arrows.x, yend=down.arrows$STOP), 
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, "cm")),
                 colour = 'green4') + 
    geom_text_repel(size = 3,
                    aes(label = down.arrows$GENE),
                    color = 'black',
                    segment.color = 'black') +
    theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

After that I would like to merge the points in 1 ggplot, so it's important to distinguish `up` and `down`

Comment: Does this help [Change direction of arrows in geom_spoke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173710/change-direction-of-arrows-in-geom-spoke)? And for next time, please remember to make your example reproducible.

Comment: @Henrik no, because this take has scattered arrows that their starting point is > ending point or vice-versa. This means that directionality is defined like this. Hence the arrows are automatically set to point to the right direction. In my case, I don't want to indicate direction (in going up,down,left,right). I want to indicate something else.

Comment: @Henrik check again please

Comment: @hENRIK i'm just dum. All I had to do was, reverse the start coordinates with the end coordinates for the down-facing arrows...

Answer (score 1):

Solution is a lil-bit of a hack. But it took me sometime to think about it. Just reverse the start and stop for the `down-facing` arrows.

Instead of this:

```
ggplot(down.arrows, aes(down.arrows.x, down.arrows$START)) +
    geom_segment(aes(xend=down.arrows.x, yend=down.arrows$STOP), 
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, "cm")),
                 colour = 'green4') + 
    geom_text_repel(size = 3,
                    aes(label = down.arrows$GENE),
                    color = 'black',
                    segment.color = 'black') +
    theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

Do this:

```
ggplot(down.arrows, aes(down.arrows.x, down.arrows$STOP)) +   # This is all it took
    geom_segment(aes(xend=down.arrows.x, yend=down.arrows$START), # and this
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, "cm")),
                 colour = 'green4') + 
    geom_text_repel(size = 3,
                    aes(label = down.arrows$GENE),
                    color = 'black',
                    segment.color = 'black') +
    theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```